# Jetpack Compose : Hoisitng click state from DropDownItems to DropDownMenu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What i am trying to do is to close the TopBar dropdown menu after clicking the dropdown item. It can be easily done, if i am putting the dropdown items directly inside the dropdown menu. But here i am trying to separate it as a composable for readability.

Here is my `TopAppBar`

```
@Composable
fun TopBar(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState,
    event: (AdminLaunchEvents) -> Unit,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = "Main App Admin Area", fontSize = 18.sp)
        },
        actions = {
            OverflowMenu() {
                SettingsDropDownItem(onClick = {})
                ModeDropDownItem(onClick = {})
                LogoutDropDownItem(onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = true
                })
            }
        },
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        contentColor = Color.White
    )
    if (openDialog.value) {
        LogOutComponent(openDialog = openDialog, event = event,navController = navController)
    }
}
```

And this is the `OverFlowMenu` composable which contains the DropDown Menu

```
@Composable
fun OverflowMenu(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    IconButton(onClick = {
        showMenu = !showMenu
    }) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.MoreVert,
            contentDescription = "More",
        )
    }
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = showMenu,
        onDismissRequest = { showMenu = false }
    ) {
        content()        
    }
}
```

Now given below is the `DropDownItem`.

```
@Composable
fun SettingsDropDownItem(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = onClick) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.Settings,
            contentDescription = "Settings",
            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Text("Settings")
    }
}
```

What i am trying to do is, when i click the `SettingsDroDownItem`, i need to capture the click event in the `OverFlowMenu` composable to make the `showMenu` `false`, so as the hide the `DropdownMenu`. I can get the click event in the `TopAppBar`, but how to get it on `DropDownMenu`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The first option is moving `showMenu` state out of `OverflowMenu`, as this is not the only composable which depends on the value. Something like this:
   `OverFlowMenu`:

   ```
   @Composable
   fun OverflowMenu(showMenu: Bool, setShowMenu: (Bool) -> Unit, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   `TopBar`:

   ```
   actions = {
       var (showMenu, setShowMenu) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
       OverflowMenu(showMenu, setShowMenu) {
           SettingsDropDownItem(onClick = {
               openDialog.value = true
               setShowMenu(false)
           })
       }
   },
   ```
2. An other options is creating something like `OverflowMenuScope`, and running `SettingsDropDownItem` on this scope so it can close the menu itself:
   `OverflowMenu`:

   ```
   interface OverflowMenuScope {
       fun closeMenu()
   }

   @Composable
   fun OverflowMenu(content: @Composable OverflowMenuScope.() -> Unit) {
       var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
       val scope = remember {
           object: OverflowMenuScope {
               override fun closeMenu() {
                   showMenu = false
               }
           }
       }
       //...
       DropdownMenu(
           expanded = showMenu,
           onDismissRequest = { showMenu = false }
       ) {
           scope.content()
       }
   }
   ```

   `SettingsDropDownItem`:

   ```
   @Composable
   fun OverflowMenuScope.SettingsDropDownItem(onClick: () -> Unit) {
       DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
           closeMenu()
           onClick()
       }) {
           Icon(
               Icons.Filled.Settings,
               contentDescription = "Settings",
               modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
           )
           Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
           Text("Settings")
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @shijilal could you confirmed what was the problem if any, with the first method? That's what I'd recommend

Comment: @MARSK Haven't tried that first one now. It is something i had tired previously, but couldn't get it working. Haven't tried to make it work. The second one seems to be a newer  thing to me.. so tried that

Comment: @MARSK Why do you think, i should use the first method?

Comment: The first method is what you would actually use most of the time. I mean such scenarios are too common to create a scope for every single time you encounter them. The second method is just Philip's force of habit gone crazy. He loves way too overcomplicating things. Never mind.

Comment: @MARSK If you're creating `SettingsDropDownItem` to be used only inside `OverflowMenu`, the second method is much cleaner and the code is easier to read.

Comment: I'd agree with the cleaner part, but not at all with the easier to read part.